# Most performant way of comparing a huge array in vb with records in sql server?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, vb.net, performance, logic

I have a 2D array in vb.net (for test purposes it is only 1000 rows, but the actual will be up to 2.5m).

The array can be split into three groups, which is dependent on two fields in SQL server, TD and UID:

- TDnomatch
- TDmatchUIDmatch
- TDmatchUIDnomatch

Logic:
[image]

My original code just looped through each row of the array

Pseudo-code to show structure

```
for row_id  = 0 to upper_bound      
 "select ... where TD = " & Pricetable(0, rowid)
  executereader
  if sqlreader.Hasrows()
      ... (getting UID from reader and other validation)      
      closereader
      If UID <> UID_VBarray
           "delete from ... "
           executenonquery
           InsertPrices(command, UID, rowid)
      end if
  else
      closereader
      InsertPrices(command, UID, rowid)
  end if
next row_id
```

This is ridiculously slow, about 3 minutes for 1200 records. I assume this is because of all the overhead communication between sql server and vb.net.

So I want to minimize the amount of queries, but **the question is if I should do the logic in SQL Server or in vb.net**.

To read in every record (TD, UID) from sql server into another array in vb.net seems like overkill (not to mention that I might need more ram lol), but then the logic is easy and I can just do a few inserts.

Could I send the entire array to SQL Server? Is it advisable to send a query with a where ... IN / not in (List of 2.5 million elements) (obviously building string with loop concatenation)

Comment: Put the data in the database, add proper indexes and write a query that will return the results you want.

Comment: `"select ... where TD = " & Pricetable(0, rowid)` - no. If you still want it on client-side, read it from DB all at once or by portions. You've probably found the slowest way to do this.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - Dont what? the rows that are being deleted must be deleted, because they are no longer real. (Stock prices before changes due to splits and dividends)

Comment: I was responding to the title - *don't* pull the data to the client, it's the slowest way possible. You can find differences with a LEFT JOIN. You can use a LEFT JOIN in the FROM clause of an INSERT or DELETE statement, which means you can easily write statements to delete missing records or add new ones. Performance will be *very* fast if the columns used in the JOIN are part of an index, typically the primary key

Comment: For example you can write `DELETE Target FROM Target left outer join source on source.ID=target.ID where source.ID is null` to delete rows that don't appear in `source`

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt even think about using another table, lol,  I only thought through the logic on the client side.

Comment: Since you have to add and update rows on the SQL Server, then your best bet is to use SqlBulkCopy() to inject your array with 2.5 million rows into a temp table.  Then use SQL statements (such as MERGE) to compare and update the permanent table in SQLServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with previous comments - SQL is the best for performance on this task, however, I did want to mention a couple of tricks i've had whilst dealing with large amounts of data.

Dictionaries - have a good look at these as they are incrdibly faster with large data than lists and in some of my cases faster than SQL. Dependant on what your outcome needs to be, i can load ~ 750k email records into a dictionary < 4 seconds from SQL but once you have them on the client I can pull any one of them instantaneously, and querying them is milliseconds!

You're correct on the RAM, loading all the data into the client machine is very costly and not to mention can get corrupt easily especially if updates to recodsets are going on in the background.

If you do want to query SQL bear in mind the `con.open ...>>stuff>> ... con.close` takes a long time to process, so try to refrain from querying each individual record. Always grab the data you need all at once and then (if required) do the calcualtions after.

I know this isn't an answer, just hopefully it gives you some good pointers and ideas :)

hth
Chicken

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting the array to a datatable and using sqlbulkcopy. Then I just used sql commands and let the logic lay within my sql. Note: I'm using dynamic sql because sql injection is not a threat, this is for the users own local instance.

```
 For rowid = 0 To upper_bound
        If PriceTable(0, rowid) <> Nothing Then
            workrow = DTPriceTable.NewRow()
            For columnid = 0 To 14
                workrow(columnid) = PriceTable(columnid, rowid)
            Next
            DTPriceTable.Rows.Add(workrow)
            i += 1
            If i > 10000 Then
                i = 0
                SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Preparing records to be written", 0, 7, rowid / upper_bound)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Write Prices to empty table", 1, 7)

    Using bc As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(myConn)
        bc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.NewPrices"
        Try
            bc.WriteToServer(DTPriceTable)
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote to db")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed to write to Db")
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using

    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Transfering splits and dividends to SavedInfo Table", 2, 7)
    command.CommandText =
        "Insert into SavedInfo
        Select ticker, [date], ex_dividend, split_ratio, tickerdate
        From [dbo].[NewPrices]
        Where ex_dividend <> 0 Or split_ratio <> 1"
    Dim DailySplitsandDiv As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Update the UID column
    command.CommandText = "
        update NewPrices
        Set UID_All_Concat = CONCAT([tickerdate]
          , [open]
          , [high]
          , [low]
          , [close]
          , [volume]
          , [ex_dividend]
          , [split_ratio]
          , [adj_open]
          , [adj_high]
          , [adj_low]
          , [adj_close]
          , [adj_volume])"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'New tickerdates
    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Inserting new prices", 3, 7)
    command.CommandText =
        "Insert into Prices
        Select
            np.[ticker]
          , np.[date]
          , np.[open]
          , np.[high]
          , np.[low]
          , np.[close]
          , np.[volume]
          , np.[ex_dividend]
          , np.[split_ratio]
          , np.[adj_open]
          , np.[adj_high]
          , np.[adj_low]
          , np.[adj_close]
          , np.[adj_volume]
          , np.UID_All_Concat
          , np.tickerdate
        From [dbo].[NewPrices] as np
        Left Join Prices on np.tickerdate = Prices.tickerdate
        where Prices.tickerdate Is null"

    Dim RowsInserted1 As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()


    'TD match UID no match (Historical data changed due to splits or dividends)
    'First delete the records that need to be updated
    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Updating historical prices for splits and dividends", 4, 7)
    command.CommandText =
        "Delete Prices
        From [dbo].[Prices]
        Left Join NewPrices np on np.tickerdate = Prices.tickerdate         
        where np.UID_All_Concat <> Prices.UID_All_Concat"

    Dim rowsDeletedduetoSandD As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Updating historical prices for splits and dividends", 5, 7)
    command.CommandText =
        "Insert into Prices
        Select
            np.[ticker]
            , np.[date]
            , np.[open]
            , np.[high]
            , np.[low]
            , np.[close]
            , np.[volume]
            , np.[ex_dividend]
            , np.[split_ratio]
            , np.[adj_open]
            , np.[adj_high]
            , np.[adj_low]
            , np.[adj_close]
            , np.[adj_volume]
            , np.UID_All_Concat
            , np.tickerdate

        From [dbo].[NewPrices] as np
        Left Join Prices on np.tickerdate = Prices.tickerdate           
        where Prices.tickerdate is null"

    Dim RowsInserted2 As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()


    'Cleanup NewPrices table
    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Cleanup newprices table", 6, 7)
    command.CommandText = "Delete from dbo.NewPrices"
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    SQLServerInfo.SQLUpdateInfo("Finished", 7, 7, 100)
End Sub
```